# dojo 1.9 config with custom package paths

Tags: javascript, dojo, require, amd

So I can see that the file was loaded properly from the dojoConfig reference but, when I attempt to use the module its 'undefined' any suggestions:

Updated: This will load the file, but when I throw the variable into a  console nothing comes out.  When inspecting it, I see a lot of text instead of the array of objs I placed inside.

**index.html:**

```
<script>
   dojoConfig = {
     tlmSiblingOfDojo: true,
     async: true,
     parseOnLoad: false,
     packages: [
                { name: "main", location: "/components/3.6compact/js/dojo/dojo/main"},
                { name: "jquery", location: "/scripts/libs", main: "jquery"},
                {name: "jam", location: "/scripts/mylibs", main: "lod"}
            ]
        };
    </script>
    <script src="/components/3.6compact/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

**lod.js:**

```
define([], function(){
  var lod = [{
    'level': 0,
    'resolution': 156543.033928,
    'scale': 591657527.591555
}, {
    'level': 1,
    'resolution': 78271.5169639999,
    'scale': 295828763.795777
}
 ];
 return lod;
 });
```

*app.js:**

```
require(['jam'], function(jam){
  console.log(lod);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to provide an example on something like jsfiddle where we can't specify resources by file path, but I think the problem is with the module id in your javascript. In your `dojoConfig`, the `location` property defines the path to the *directory* where modules in that package can be located.

If your `lod` module is located at in `/scripts/mylibs/lod.js`, then you'd need to require `lod/lod`:

```
require(['lod/lod'], function(lod) {
    console.log("lod module:", lod);
});
```

[Here's the documentation for dojo config](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/). I would look at the "Loader Configuration" section.

I attempted a jsfiddle anyway, which could be useful: http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/ftN6h/

Note the errors in the console:

'lod':

```
GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/scripts/mylibs/LOD.js 404 (Not Found)
```

and 'lod/lod':

```
GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/scripts/mylibs/lod.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm not familiar with the "main" property of the package config, but it looks like that's what it's using when you try to require an entire package. Maybe try changing that to "lod" so it looks for ".../lod.js"?

Comment: you seem to be on to something for some reason I can't get this to work, my dojo config is loaded on my html page and the require page is loaded after dojo, could this be the culprit.  Question was edited to reflect

Comment: You can add a `data-dojo-config` attribute to the script tag you're using to load dojo -- see the options in my jsfiddle above -- and in that attribute, you can specify your dojo config. If you still want to do it how you have it above, make sure `dojoConfig` is a global; i.e. no `var` before it.

Comment: Can you add any console errors you're getting to your question? That will probably help debug the issue you're having.

Comment: new code updates its now properly loading the file, now when I load the file name nothing is coming out in the log, I'm thinking I can try a different variable name, the one used in the define/custom module

Comment: `require(['jam'], function(jam){
      console.log(lod);
    });`

Should be `console.log(jam)` if you want to log what you've `require`ed.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, correcting the paths and package configuration was the biggie.  I had some other parts of the packages that were bombing which was also causing dojo to break so with that resolved, I'm not cooking with gas.  Thanks so much!